# Strange interaction between FiraSans and siunitx

Tags: fonts, siunitx

While using FiraSans and siunitx I noticed that the value and the units are too wide. I am using TeXLive 2016. Fira version 4.2-2016-11-12 and Siunitx 2.7-2016-11-24.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \SI{10}{\%}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's undoubtedly the bug in `mweights.sty` already mentioned today: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342831/weird-spacing-around-bold-text-when-using-custom-t1-fonts Indeed, the proposed temporary fix works.

Comment: The author of `mweights` has already answered announcing a new version is on its way to CTAN. I guess it will be deployed in TeX Live in a couple of days.